# Best Coldfusion Library for OpenID

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, openid

I am getting ready to start a project that requires using OpenID within Coldfusion 8. I have found a number of different options and was wondering what has worked the best, get's the most support, stays up to date, etc...

- [OpenID CFC](http://openid.riaforge.org/index.cfm)
- [CFOpenID](http://www.indiankey.com/cfopenid/)
- [CFKit OpenID](http://cfkitopenid.riaforge.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd vote for OpenID CFC---but maybe that's because I'm one of the project's developers... ;-)

So although I'm obviously biased, here's why I recommend OpenID CFC:

- It supports OpenID 2.0 and IS updated fairly regularly when necessary
- CFKit OpenID only supports OpenID 1.1
- CFOpenID supports OpenID 2.0, but doesn't appear to have been updated for a long time.

I don't know when Jason looked at the libraries or what issues he had, but you shouldn't have any issues if you want to use OpenID CFC. When I updated it to support OpenID 2.0 I made several changes that really simplified the API so it's really easy to use.

RPX is also a good alternative. But it's not free and since it's a third-party system you are relinquishing a little bit of control over the system.

Comment: I see where I can download an example project. However, is there some kind of walk through someplace that explains what needs to be changed/updated as looking through the code it isn't very intuitive.

Comment: After adding the project and running it as a test, I select to log in to Google. After authenticating with Google, I get sent to a page on Google that says "The page you requested is invalid." Any ideas?

Comment: There is a known bug affecting Google authentication. See the bug report for more information: http://openid.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.issue&issueid=B5F9C730-9784-BCD0-6A9735DB338B774D

I don't actually have commit access to the project so I can't fix the bug. But you can either follow the instructions in the bug report to patch the code yourself, or email me for an updated version of the code: richard at richarddavies dot us.

Comment: FYI: The project has now been updated to fix the Google authentication issue and a few other minor issues.

Answer (score 1):

When I was trying those out, they weren't being updated any longer and had some issues.

I ended up using RPX, and my life has been a lot easier since I did so.

[RPX Now](https://rpxnow.com/)