# OpenID revisited - ColdFusion only please

Tags: coldfusion, oauth, openid

In 2009, someone asked for ['the best' ColdFusion OpenID solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756748/best-coldfusion-library-for-openid).  I'd like to revisit the question again because it looks like the OpenID projects on RiaForge are getting dated.

Q: Is that because OpenID hasn't changed much?

I signed up for Google oauth, but I think that's more than what I need because oauth has to do with gaining access to someone's calendar or GMail account, and I'm just looking for the same type of login as on StackOverflow.

I watched the cfmeetup video [OAuth demystified](http://experts.adobeconnect.com/p410i3hterp/) and got lost in the explanation.  Maybe I should watch it again...

Comment: OpenID and OAuth are 2 different things...

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually using the [OpenID CFC from RIAForge](http://openid.riaforge.org/index.cfm) for a couple of projects, but I'm wondering if OpenID's day has come and gone.

Is your goal to delegate authentication to other services (Google, Yahoo, etc) or to authenticate clients on your site using a local user account? OAuth is more for the latter than the former.

There does appear to be a new player that looks to solve the same problem as OpenID: [BrowserID](https://browserid.org/).

Comment: Looks easier than Google's openid, but I really want to use openid.  I'll check out the one on RIAForge again.  Thanks!